# ubuntu freezes because i915 graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics

my ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit crashes while watching movies on Firefox or on Kodi or whatever. The crash means: the screen freezes and my system does not react on keyboard / mouse.

It has something to do with the i915 driver of my graphics card and the low latency kernel. Despite googling: I do not find other solutions. Does anyone know a simple work around? Downgrading is not an option because it is a fresh install and the problems occurred since the beginning.

kind regards,
Robert

[dmesg.log](http://www.robertsplannen.nl/dmesg.log)

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 3.19.0-31-generic

system: [ASrock Intel Q2900](http://www.asrock.nl/mb/Intel/Q2900-ITX/) 
Logitech K400r keyboard

Comment: I think I solved it: I updated the firmware of my SSD. Seems stable now despite the error message in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my own question:
1. the hanging / freezing of the system was caused by unstable firmware of the crucial SSD. Updating to the newest firmware solved the freezing problem. (never noticed this under microsoft windows OS)
2. for stability of the system it was necessary to raise the memory voltage from 1.35 to 1.55 of my q2900 motherboard. I also switched the intel cpu c1, c3 c7 cpu-power-saving-setting in the bios.

Although dmsg still has a few errors during boot, the system is stable: i.e. I can watch movies without having to reset my computer.